# Odd behaviour of array_diff

Tags: php

I am running the script below to get the difference between two arrays using array_diff but I am getting an empty array as result.

```
$a = [
    "INDEX1" => "No",
    "INDEX2" => "Yes",
    "INDEX3" => "No",
    "INDEX4" => "No"
];

$b = [
    "INDEX1" => "Yes",
    "INDEX2" => "Yes",
    "INDEX3" => "No",
    "INDEX4" => "Yes"
];

print_r( array_diff($a, $b) );

Array
(
)
```

Shouldn't I get this instead?

```
Array
(
    "INDEX1" => "No",
    "INDEX4" => "No"
)
```

Can anybody help me to understand what is happening?

Comment: The output you get is good because it compare *diff* between two arrays and here you have the exact same keys

Comment: Are you looking for [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc)?

Comment: You are right, I didn't realise of it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, @jon-stirling that was what I needed, thanks.

Comment: The array_diff() function compares the values of two (or more) arrays, and returns the differences.
Thats its give you empty array you need this array_diff_assoc (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff_assoc.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is expected: According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and **returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays**.

The only *values* you have are `yes` and `no` and both are present in both arrays.

As mentioned in the comments already, you can use `array_diff_assoc` to check on the keys as well and get the result you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_diff_assoc($a, $b)` instead. You will get:

```
Array
(
    [INDEX1] => No
    [INDEX4] => No
)
```